# ChartJS animate grid on zoom

Tags: chart.js

In have a line chart made with chartjs. For that chart I added some buttons to zoom in/out and reset the zoom. When changing the zoom value my lines animate nicely. However neither the labels on the axes nor the grid itself show any kind of transition but instead just show their new final look without any steps inbetween.
Is there some way where I can enable transitions for the grid and the labels?

Comment: as far as I know tha'ts not implemented. There is an enhancement request in github repo.